# need to change the vba code to russian language

Tags: vba, excel

anyone help to translate my userform caption to russian. Also i assigned the translate form in my excel.
printout is a form name and LG is the sheet of listed names of all countries which includes Russian. When i change the language the userform just display as "????".

```
Sub Trans_Forms_PrintOut()

    PrintOutform.Caption = Sheets("LG").[C798]
    PrintOutform.Label1.Caption = Sheets("LG").[C799]
    PrintOutform.cmdPrint.Caption = Sheets("LG").[C804]
    PrintOutform.cmdCancel.Caption = Sheets("LG").[C805]

End Sub
```

Comment: Could you show us what column C on Sheet LG contains?

Comment: Master
MonoSpace
MiniSpace
Transys
0
Поставка лифта
Получение оборудования, разгрузка в зоне хранения, проверка кол-ва ящиков, установка колёс на ящик с лебёдкой МХ
Подготовка объекта
 MASTER WHICH IS THE OUTPUT that is LG sheet COLUMN c

Comment: from D we have all countries translation for example

Comment: Russian
MonoSpace
MiniSpace
Transys

Поставка лифта
Получение оборудования, разгрузка в зоне хранения, проверка кол-ва ящиков, установка колёс на ящик с лебёдкой МХ
Подготовка объекта
Подготовка объекта, монтажная лебёдка, провешивание, ОС
Получение и перемещение инструментов в отведённые для этого места
Подготовка / транспортировка инструментов/ уборка мусора

Comment: in english we have as below

Comment: English
MonoSpace
MiniSpace
Transys
Delivery
Delivery of Lift
Receive delivery offload to storage area, check nr of crates fitt wheels to MX crate
Set-up
Set-up, Hoist, plumb, governor
Receive and transport tools to dedicated positions
Preparations /transport tools/waste handling

Comment: This is really a must-read in your case https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/ (written by the CEO of SO)

Comment: Well the above code seems to work for me, in terms of changing the captions from specific cells, have you checked whether any of these cells contain the string "????"

Comment: It isn't enough to have a language installed, you must also have the script of that language. Otherwise the characters will just be displayed as question marks or little squares. Unfortunately, this means that you can't influence what the user can see on his machine. Best I know foreign script will only be available by default if that language is the default language on the reading computer. You can circumvent part of this by using Unicode characters but this may not work with MsgBox.

Comment: Thanks all for ur comments